# R How to merge 2 data frames based on ID and latest status Date?

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I'm trying to merge 2 data frames that look like this:

```
library(data.table)

#transactions
colNames<-c("id","tran")
df2 <- data.table(c("010","010","030","210","310","050"), as.Date(c("2012-12-28","2014-01-01","2011-07-05","2015-04-05","2013-07-05","2012-08-01")))
names(df2) <- colNames

#status change
colNames<-c("id","status")
df1 <- data.table(c("010","010","010","030","030","210","210","310","050"),
as.Date(c("2012-10-28","2013-11-01","2014-01-01","2011-05-09","2011-08-04","2013-07-06","2015-01-01","2013-05-04","2010-09-10")))
names(df1) <- colNames
```

## Into the following result:

```
df3
    id       tran       status
1: 010 2012-12-28   2012-10-28
2: 010 2014-01-02   2014-01-01
3: 030 2011-07-05   2011-05-09
4: 210 2015-04-05   2015-01-01
5: 310 2013-07-05   2013-05-04
6: 050 2012-08-01   2010-09-10
```

- There's more transactions than status changes.
- The dates are well formatted.
- There's many columns in each data frame but these are the
  important ones for the merge.

Essentially, all transactions happen at some point after a status change. I'm trying to merge all transactions with their appropriate status change for each ID. The tricky part is that the dates are almost never the same. 
**I need the status change date that it was for each transaction**...

I'm looking at ?merge but I don't see how it can do something like that. Maybe ?aggregate but how would it know that the aggregation is conditional on another data frame?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have a mistake at the third line, but this probably should do `df2[df1, status := i.status, on = .(id, tran = status), roll = -Inf]` or maybe you want `df2[df1, status := i.status, on = .(id, tran = status), roll = "nearest"]` ?

Comment: Fixed the mistake. Nice, the first version looks like what I'm after. If you put it as a solution I'll accept. Is there a place where I can read about that kind of manipulation? It's new to me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: See [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/understanding-data-table-rolling-joins/) perhaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply perform rolling join.

```
df2[df1, status := i.status, on = .(id, tran = status), roll = -Inf]
df2
#     id       tran     status
# 1: 010 2012-12-28 2012-10-28
# 2: 010 2014-01-01 2014-01-01
# 3: 030 2011-07-05 2011-05-09
# 4: 210 2015-04-05 2015-01-01
# 5: 310 2013-07-05 2013-05-04
# 6: 050 2012-08-01 2010-09-10
```

- `roll = -Inf` just means that for each incident in `df2`, we want to match the closest lower incident in `df1` no matter how far it is.
- `status := i.status` means that we want to create a column called `status` in `df2` *by reference* (in place) while borrowing the matching values from `df1$status`. `i.` states for the column from the table in the `i`th locating in `df2`